# Using Devise, how can I have different configuration options for admins and users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Devise, I have an admin model and a user model. I want to specify different configuration options for each model. At the moment, all of my Devise configuration is in `/config/initializors/devise.rb`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two things for each: route helpers (which will end up in `routes.rb`) and devise field helpers (which will end up in your two models).

When you run `rails generate devise user` and `rails generate devise admin`, you should get setup with what you need for both to get started.

Oh, and chase it down with `rake db:migrate`, as depending on your needs, various columns will get added to both tables.

(If you're asking for setting different *global* configuration options for different models, I'm not sure how to go about doing that, actually, if it's even possible.)